# Some items are blurry in Kubuntu

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, icons, tearing

Some items in Menu, System Setting and other icons are blurry.

Kubuntu 20.04.2
GPU: AMD 7400m

here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell what is blurry from your screen shot, because it is a jpg format which inherently loses information, and it is not a lossless full resolution image (which would be too big any way). Please edit your question and point out / describe what seems blurry to you. Is it the window decorations, the icons, the fonts?

Comment: Do this... Use the screenshot tool (Spectacle) to take a screenshot of a rectangular *region* where the icon or widget appears blurry. Save it as a PNG file. If there is an application where the icon or widget does *not* seem blurry, also take a screen shot of that rectangular region. Please add both screenshots to your question above, and I'll take a look at both to see if I can spot anything. (Are you ~sure~ the fonts are not blurry, because that is a know issue, and I could point you to the right spot to report that. If it is more than fonts that are blurry there could be another cause).

Comment: these screen shots is totally clear! if zoom in,you can view display blur, i changed fonts and forced DPI to 96 and some other changes in compositor setting, but nothing helped.

Comment: JPEG by definition is not a "clear" image format (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG). Nevertheless, take a look at my comment on this question regarding a bug with fonts in KDE: https://askubuntu.com/q/1320941/100356. I wonder if the same issue that is causing blurry fonts is also affecting other UI elements?